# How to duplicate a file and a symlink to that file?

Tags: bash, macos, unix, symlink

I am trying to duplicate a folder that contains a text file and a symlink to a text file.
How do I achieve the following duplication of Folder 1:

```
|---- Folder1
|     |---- file1.txt
|     |---- symlink_to_file1.txt
```

Now I want to duplicate this folder to become:

```
|---- Folder1_copy
|     |---- file1_copy.txt
|     |---- symlink_to_file1_copy.txt
```

Usually the names would not change to include "_copy", I just added this to make the example clear.

Currently if I "ctrl+c", "ctrl+v" my folder structure I get:

```
|---- Folder1_copy
|     |---- file1_copy.txt
|     |---- symlink_to_file1.txt
```

SOLUTION TO ABOVE:

`rsync -av Folder1/* Folder1_copy/`

However *THIS DOES NOT WORK* in the case of duplicating:

```
|---- Folder1
|     |---- Nested_folder1
|     |     |---- file1.txt
|     |---- Nested_folder2
|     |     |---- Nested_folder3
|     |     |     |---- symlink_to_file1.txt
```

After running `rsync -av Folder1/* Folder1_copy/` on the above file structure, the new `symlink_to_file1_copy.txt` symlink will still point to the original `file1.txt`

Comment: try `cp -r Folder1 Folder1_copy` .

Comment: try `rsync -av Folder1/ Folder1_copy/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `rsync -av Folder1/* Folder1_copy/`
I tested this myself and that seems to achieve the setup you wanted. The first solution suggested in the comments doesn't preserve the link, while the second one places a copy of the whole directory Folder1 into Folder1_copy.

Important caveat: for any symlinks in Folder1 which are copied to Folder1_copy to actually point to other copied files in Folder1_copy rather than the original files in Folder1, those symlinks need to be created to point to files based on their *relative path* within Folder1 instead of an absolute path.

Comment: This works for the files which are in the same directory, as asked in my question and I am very thankful for this answer. However I'm finding it does not work for a symlink which is in a more complex position relative to the file. e.g. "folder1/nested_folder1/file.txt" and "folder1/nested_folder2/nested_folder3/symlink_to_file.txt"

Comment: From within Nested_folder3, I find that when I create the original symlink to be relative to its location, a.k.a. `ln -s ../../Nested_folder1/file1.txt symlink_to_file1` the original `rsync` solution I suggested will create a symlink copy which points to file1_copy.txt like you want. If the original symlink is based on an absolute path however, a.k.a. created like `ln -s ~/Folder1/Nested_folder1/file1.txt symlink_to_file1`, then yes, the new symlink copy will point to the original file1.txt.

Comment: Interesting. My problem is that the symlinks I am dealing with are not made by myself, I am trying to copy a library. I think my next approach will be to find out how to replace all absolute symlinks with relative symlinks recursively in a directory. Thank you very much for your help!